# Function created with compilation errors

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to 
create a function that accepts an input parameter `k_city_id` (datatype `number`) and returns the corresponding `stadium_name` for the specified city from table `k_venue`. If there is more than one venue in a city, then it should raise a `too_namy_rows` exception with the text *'This City has more than one venue'*.

This is my function:

```
create or replace function find_venuee(k_city_id in number)
    return k_venue.stadium_name%type
is
    venue_name k_venue.stadium_name%type;
begin
    select stadium_name into venue_name from k_venue
    where city_id = k_city_id;

    return venue_name;
exception
    when too_many_rows then
        venue_name := 'This City has more than one venue'; 
        return venue_name;
end;
/
```

It's creating the function with compilation errors. What is wrong with code?

Comment: add the error to question and format your code

Comment: Run `show error` to find out what's wrong

Comment: We can only guess at what the compilation errors might be until you tell us. http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Answer (score 1):

We don't know how that table looks like (so I created my own); everything seems to be OK (see the example below).

Could you post something like that too, so that we could see what you did and how Oracle responded?

```
SQL> create table k_venue (city_id number, stadium_name varchar2(50));

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> create or replace function find_venuee (k_city_id in number)
  2    return k_venue.stadium_name%type
  3  is
  4    venue_name k_venue.stadium_name%type;
  5  begin
  6    select stadium_name
  7      into venue_name
  8      from k_venue
  9      where city_id = k_city_id;
 10
 11    return venue_name;
 12
 13  exception
 14    when too_many_rows then
 15      venue_name := 'This City has more than one venue';
 16      return venue_name;
 17  end;
 18  /

Function created.

SQL>
SQL> insert into k_venue values (1, 'Stadium A');

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> select find_Venuee(1) From dual;

FIND_VENUEE(1)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Stadium A

SQL>
SQL> insert into k_venue values (1, 'Stadium B');

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> select find_Venuee(1) From dual;

FIND_VENUEE(1)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
This City has more than one venue

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not have dynamic return type of a funciton. You have to create a type as oracle pl/sql object and then use it or Right down "Varchar2" as you said function will be returning venue name based on the city id received.

Please find the code below:

```
create or replace function find_venuee(k_city_id in number)
return varchar2 is
venue_name k_venue.stadium_name%type;
begin
select stadium_name into venue_name from k_venue
where city_id = k_city_id;
return venue_name;
exception
when too_many_rows then
venue_name := 'This City has more than one venue'; 
return venue_name;
end;
/
```

Hope this will help.

Thanks
Ankit.